# Using EF6 and EF5 Tools side by side in VS2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have this situation where I want to start using EF6 for new projects, because EF6 is the latest version, but I still want to be able the work on my old projects that use EF5.

To use EF6 in VS2012, I need to install the [Entity Framework 6 Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39945), but the problem is that install instructions say that "When you install the RC1 tooling it will replace the EF Designer that was included in Visual Studio 2012"

So to my understating, VS2012 will be unable to work with the old projects that use EF5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EF6 desing tools support both EF5 and EF6